# Phone doesn't turn wifi off and weirdly transmits data

Tags: wi-fi, standby

When i wake up my phone(kitkat,cm11) from standby, it always transmits data through wifi and than stops transmitting/recieving data. It gives the feeling it always transmits/recieves while sleeping.

I turned down all location services in various places, i set wifi to turn on "only when connected to power" , turned of "scanning always availble" , but still no help.

What is the cause , and how do i track this down?

Comment: I'd start [checking the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info). Some [firewall app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall) with logging functionality might also help. As it happens even with WiFi off (the app obviously re-enabling WiFi), you can narrow down candidates using a [Permission Checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379), concentrating on those with the [`CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) permission.

Comment: Glad to hear! Mind writing up an answer? Which app you chose, which steps you performed – and which culprit you identified? Could help others in similar situations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh sure. I used the firewall, afwall+ ,turned it on( and used whitelist - blocking everything ) , turned logging on. made phone sleep. Than turned it on - and on the firewall log - i've seen the sources of traffic - all pointing to google, which i can live with.

Comment: Slight misunderstanding: I've meant "answer" as in  "pushing the 'answer your own question" button, giving the details there, then accept the answer :) Other than a comment, that marks your issue "solved", and thus easy to identify as "having a solution" :) See our [help/self-answer](/help/self-answer) page for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed Izzi's advice and it worked. Here's what i did:

I used the firewall app, afwall+ ,turned it on( and used whitelist - blocking everything ) , turned logging on.

made phone sleep.

Than turned it on - and on the firewall log - i've seen the sources of traffic - all pointing to google, which i can live with - so i didn't continue further.